# I want Javascript popup into PHP

Tags: javascript

I want this code

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" 
   onclick="popup('http://www.example.com/example.html')"> More Information Here</a>
```

into this code (just replace the link into a popup link)

```
<?php
if (!empty($accessibility_rating)) {
    echo "<li>Accessibility Rated: " 
    .$accessibility_rating 
    ." **<a href='http://www.example.com/example.html' target='_blank'>"
    ."More Information Here</a>**</li>"; 
}
?>
```

spend hours, I miss something

Comment: Please show us the best of your several hours work...

Comment: @Bartdude please be polite :/

Comment: I don't really understand what is your problem, is it that you can't use `"` in your echo ?

Comment: @gabe > I'm being very polite. Coming to a community, not reading [the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), not showing any effort and asking people for help could be considered quite impolite on the other side. Close & down votes seems to indicate I'm not the only one to think that way.

Comment: @Bartdude the comment was not necessary.

Comment: This type of comment is very usual when a poster doesn't show what he's tried, like in this case. I admit the sarcasm may not have been necessary, but when you do the same remark several times a day, you can't help it sometimes :-) Your comment, on the other side, was totaly useless. Now if you wish to be more helpfull or polite with the OP, just post an answer or a comment of any use to him.

Answer (score 2):

Just escape the `"` characters?

```
<?php
    if (!empty($accessibility_rating)) {
        echo "<li>Accessibility Rated: " 
        .$accessibility_rating
        ." **<a href=\"javascript: void(0)\" "
        ."onclick=\"popup('http://www.example.com/example.html')\">"
        ." More Information Here</a>**</li>";
    }
?>
```